# Insert in the title attribute a dynamic title in wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in the template for my site's archives

```
printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $post_link ), get_the_post_thumbnail( $post, 'large' ));
```

How do I insert inside the "title" attribute a dynamic title using the same code?

[there is as screen of actually frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E60gL.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I think you can add a `title` attribute in the 3rd param of `get_the_post_thumbnail` like so:

```
printf( '%s', esc_url( $post_link ), get_the_post_thumbnail( $post, 'large', array('title' => 'your title here') ));
```